# PHP Normalizer: Fatal error: Class 'Normalizer' not found

Tags: php, special-characters, normalization

I am trying to normalise a string, but it gives an error,

> Fatal error: Class 'Normalizer' not
>   found in C:xx.php on line xx

As far as I understand I just need to do this if I want to use the Normalizer class,

```
$string = "Löic & René";
$normalise = Normalizer::normalize($string);
```

I have turned on the php extension which is `php_intl`. is there anything else I should turn on to use this type of class? or have I done something incorrectly?

I even tried this code from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) but I have the same error,

```
$char_A_ring = "\xC3\x85"; // 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE' (U+00C5)
$char_combining_ring_above = "\xCC\x8A";  // 'COMBINING RING ABOVE' (U+030A)

$char_1 = Normalizer::normalize( $char_A_ring, Normalizer::FORM_C );
$char_2 = Normalizer::normalize( 'A' . $char_combining_ring_above, Normalizer::FORM_C );

echo urlencode($char_1);
echo ' '; 
echo urlencode($char_2);
```

Any ideas?

I am on Wamp server 2.2.11 by the way.

Thanks.

Comment: Turning on php_intl fixed it for me.

Comment: I managed to solve this by using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71797367/3223576

Answer (score -3):

you need PHP  5 >= 5.3.0 for this reason

do you restarted your web service?

Comment: yes i have restarted the web service. i am using wamp server... can't understand it why it won;t work!