# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Normalizer' not found in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to do a composer install in a Laravel project cloned from git.

But im getting some errors.

The first one that I solved was:

`- phpunit/phpunit[8.5.0, ..., 8.5.x-dev] require ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.`

By doing:

`sudo apt install php7-4-xml php7.4-mbstring`

But now when I do a  `composer update` or `composer install` I’m getting this answer:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Normalizer' not found in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php:129`.

`Stack trace:`

```
#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(516): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Helper::strlenWithoutDecoration()
#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(576): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar::Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\{closure}()
#2 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\{closure}()
#3 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(589): preg_replace_callback()
#4 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(414): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->buildLine()
#5 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(323): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->display()
#6 /usr/share/php/Composer/Util/Loop.php(85): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->start()
#7 /usr/share/php/Compos in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php on line 129

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Normalizer' not found in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php:129
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(516): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Helper::strlenWithoutDecoration()
#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(576): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar::Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\{closure}()
#2 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\{closure}()
#3 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(589): preg_replace_callback()
#4 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(414): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->buildLine()
#5 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/ProgressBar.php(323): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->display()
#6 /usr/share/php/Composer/Util/Loop.php(85): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar->start()
#7 /usr/share/php/Compos in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php on line 129
```

Comment: see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597146/class-normalizer-not-found-in-php-5-3-8#:~:text=Left%2Dclick%20on%20the%20WAMP,fine%20while%20it%20doesn't. )if this helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class Normalizer not found (in PHP 5.3.8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597146/class-normalizer-not-found-in-php-5-3-8)

Comment: Please share more details. Which version of Symfony do you use? Searching through some versions, I could not find the code that triggers this problem.

Comment: When I run the "Composer" command, I get the same error. I can tell you the version of Composer, which is installed. But symfony I have been unable to find the version. The version of Composer is 2.0.9.

Comment: Why not update that version? It's more than a year old, and maybe that's a bug that has been fixed?

Comment: Also, as your code seems to run in `/usr/share/php`: how did it get there? Did you install Symfony over your system's package manager?

Comment: Sorry for the absence and the delay.
Finally, due to others problems with the OS I've decided to reinstall the OS. I was able to install the project without any problem after that.

Answer (score 40):

### It requires php-intl to be installed

Normalizer class comes with the php internationalization extension (php-intl). It must be installed for using the Normalizer class

on debian i did

```
sudo apt install php-intl
```

It should fix the problem

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: if you have specific php version you can use, like sudo apt install php8.1-intl

Answer (score 6):

Firstly you can try to install php-intl package

```
sudo apt install php-intl
```

If it doesn't help, you can run following commands one by one to upgrade php version to 8.1. (for Debian based OS):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt install php8.1 php8.1-cli php8.1-fpm php8.1-apcu php8.1-opcache php8.1-common php8.1-curl php8.1-zip php8.1-mcrypt php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring php8.1-xml php8.1-gd php8.1-imagick php8.1-xmlrpc php8.1-maxminddb
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1
```

Then check php version:

```
php --version
```

This helped me to fix error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and managed to fix it by uninstalling composer, then reinstalling composer correctly from the right repositories. I was using `sudo-apt get composer`, which was the issue.

Comment: It must be: sudo apt-get install composer, that not solve the issue...

Comment: Thanks for the correction, yes, don't use that. rather Install from the official composer script

Comment: Another way to install Composer:
`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

Answer (score 0):

To solve it you need to install newer version of php 8.1

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. From my POV, nothing in the question indicates that PHP 8.1 would magically solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This could be fixed by installing Composer directly from their website.

Remove the one installed with the package manager of your OS, then run:

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`